# Perl Insert Specific character in String

Tags: perl, for-loop, sequence, bioinformatics

I have two Characters first Sequences and Second Quality.
Second Quality show first sequence`s quality like below.

```
1. ACTGACTGACTG
2. KKKKKKKKKKKK
```

After processing(Aligned) first sequence it will change as below

```
1. ACT-GACTG-ACTG
2. KKKKKKKKKKKK
```

So I have to extend Second information also as below (Using space)

```
1. ACT-GACTG-ACTG
2. KKK KKKKK KKKK
```

I already did using for loop and check each character for first one and make a space for second one.

is there any easy and simple way to make it?

Thank you!

Comment: How did you add the dashes into the first string?

Comment: That is Bioinformatics Algorithm aligned Sequence, Second information I cannot aligned just need to be follow first string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Positional Information](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Position-information) and [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str1 = 'ACT-GACTG-ACTG';
my $str2 = 'KKKKKKKKKKKK';

while ($str1 =~ /\W/g) {
    substr $str2, $-[0], 0, ' ';
}

print "$str1\n";
print "$str2\n";
```

Outputs:

```
ACT-GACTG-ACTG
KKK KKKKK KKKK
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to add a space to Quality each time you add a dash to Sequence.

Or, you can loop over Sequence and check the positions of dashes, and insert spaces to Quality based on that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $sequence = 'ACT-GACTG-ACTG';
my $quality  = 'KKKKKKKKKKKK';

my $pos = 0;
while (0 <= ($pos = index $sequence, '-', $pos)) {
    substr $quality, $pos++, 0, ' ';
}

print "$quality\n";
```